# What is the function in R for the Excel function =NORM.S.INV(rand())?

Tags: r, excel, function

I need to convert Excel function  =NORM.S.INV(rand()). I tried with rnorm(1000,0,1), but the results do not seem to be right in the sense of distribution. What should be the R function for Excel's NORM.S.INV(rand())?

I would like the distribution of rnorm(1,0,1) or qnorm(runif(1))

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `qnorm(runif(1))`

Comment: Thank you! I am using qnorm(runif(1, min=0, max=1)) but the resulting distribution is different from Excel's. Quite puzzled.

Answer (score 5):

With NORM.S.INV() you get the quantiles of the normal distribution. Im not sure why you want this from a random generated variable. `qnorm()` gives you the quantiles of the normal distribution which is the equivalent to NORM.S.INV() in R. With `rnorm()` you generate normal distributed random variables.
Of course you can change the mean and the standard deviation for not standard normal distributed random variables.

Comment: Thank you! NORM.S.INV(P) returns the standard normal statistic when you enter the probability.  So if you enter a probability of 0.5, then the function will return the following Z statistic that represents the 50th percentile: 50% of the z values are below it.  If you enter 75%, then the function returns a value that is in the 75th percentile, and so forth.

Comment: RAND() is random number generator that generates from 0 to 1.

Comment: OK. Now I am using R function qnorm(runif(1, min=0, max=1)) to replace Excel's NORM.S.INV(RAND()). But the resulting distribution looks different.

Comment: Try ```qnorm(x)```, where x is a fixed value and compare this to the function ```NORM.S.INV()``` with the same value. If you take ```runif(1,min=0,max=1)``` the results will be different because you draw a random variable. This one will not be the same as in Excel.